# Blank Page after enabling compilation in Magento

Tags: magento

I am getting a blank page for configuration and other section in the Magento admin page. That is, when I enable the "Enable" section of compilation from system >> Tools >> Compilation,I am getting this blank page. So I have commented out few section in the index.php to solve this blank page error:

Reference : http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/10298-Blank-page-after-enabling-Magento-Compiler

After disabling above lines the Compiler Status is always showing as Disabled.

How can solve this ?

Comment: That is because, commenting those lines, as the board member of this forum is saying it, is to have the opportunity to get back on your Magento admin. This does not fix any issue though, you will have to uncomment does lines and find the issue if you want your Magento code to be compiled. So you actually are commenting out the line that tell Magento to use compiled files if that config is enable, that is why your Compiler status display disabled.

Comment: You have a module that doesn't like the compiler. Did you do a recompile before the first time you enabled the compiler? You currently have it manually shut off which is why it is disabled.